# Why does this class inheritance cause an infinite recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator

I'm attempting to DRY up decorators in a Rails project.

Essentially, I want to delegate any missing methods to the resource object (or the resource object's class).

Here's a simplified example

```
# Decorator base class
class Decorator
    attr_accessor :resource

    private

    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
        self.resource.send(name, *args, &block)
    end

    # infinite recursion happens here
    def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
        self.resource.class.send(name, *args, &block)
    end

end

# Decorator class that will be used
class UserCreator < Decorator
    attr_reader :user
    def initialize(params)
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        self.resource = @user
    end

    def save
        # do special stuff with user object
        if @user.save
            # perhaps do some more stuff after the save
            true
        else
            # perhaps handle the error here
            false
        end
    end

end

# A simple controller example
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def create
        @user = UserCreator.new(params)

        if @user.save
            render :json => @user
        else
            render :json => @user.errors
        end
    end
end
```

However, in the class `Decorator` an infinite recursion happens in the class (singleton) method `self.method_missing`.  It's passing `resource` as the `name` argument in that method.

I am trying to wrap my head around the control flow of what's going on here.  A method `resource` exists in the base `Decorator` class via `attr_accessor`, so I thought, the subclass `UserCreator` also has this method.  So I'm not sure why it thinks `resource` is a missing method.  If I get rid of the `Decorator` superclass and just implement the `method_missing`s in the `UserCreator` class, all works as expected.

Any help in implementing this base class to work as expected is greatly appreciated, so I don't have to implement the same `method_missing` methods in every decorator.

Comment: Oops.  Yeah a typo.  Good eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `method_missing` is a class method. Therefore, inside this method `self` refers to the class, not an instance.

However, the method tries to access `self.resource` which is an attribute of an instance, not the class.

Since the `Decorator` class has no `resource` attribute, `method_missing` is called again ... and again ... and again ...

> I am trying to wrap my head around the control flow of what's going on here.
>   A method resource exists in the base Decorator class via attr_accessor,

It exists in the **instances** of the Decorator class but not in the class itself.

> so I thought, the subclass UserCreator also has this method.

The **instances** of the UserCreator subclass have it, but not the subclass itself.

Comment: Very well explained.  Thank you.